# ASP.NET MVC event that happens just before action is called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to set the value of `Thread.CurrentCulture` based on some route data, but I can't find an event to hook to that fires after the routes are calculated and before the action method is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could write a custom [action filter attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx):

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // This method is executed before calling the action
        // and here you have access to the route data:
        var foo = filterContext.RouteData.Values["foo"];
        // TODO: use the foo route value to perform some action

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And then you could decorate your base controller with this custom attribute. And here's a [blog post](http://www.iansuttle.com/blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-Action-Filter-for-Localized-Sites.aspx) illustrating a sample implementation of such filter.

Comment: In MVC3 you don't in the base controller: support for global filters (and MVC already installs one in `Global.asax.cs`).

Comment: @Richard, sure but by the time I answered this question MVC 3 wasn't yet released :-) Also it wasn't tagged with MVC 3.

Comment: I know -- but it is *now* true (I should have add a "now" in there) and remember SO is part wiki.

Comment: @Richard, then don't hesitate to modify my answer to include this information. Personally I don't go through my 7546 answers everytime a new version of the framework comes out in order to update them :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to apply the culture on every action, you could create a base controller and override the `OnActionExecuting` method.

Comment: That works too. I'm guessing it's executed at the same time the attribute is. Interesting how it offers both options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the filter to all controllers, not just select ones, you can add it to the "global filters". You do this in `Application_Start()` in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomFilterAttribute ()); // ADDED

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```