# Observe begin request and end request (Not before action) Asp MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, httpwebrequest, umbraco

I am using Asp MVC, My ApplicationEventHandler inherit from :IApplicationEventHandler

I Want a function to be executed when the request is begin and when the request is end.

**How can I observe the BeginRequest and EndRequest ?**

Thank in advance

Comment: you can use different filters in mvc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Filter is per action. I want to execute function one time at the begging of the request.

Comment: please refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpApplication(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC event that happens just before action is called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104107/asp-net-mvc-event-that-happens-just-before-action-is-called)

Comment: It's not duplicate. I don't want before action. I need on Request Begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HttpModule to hook into the beginning of the request, but that's a bit dirty for an MVC app, it will also execute on ANYTHING that runs through the .Net pipeline, not just your MVC routes.

You can create a Global Filter that will execute on all Routes, but then have it ignore any of your partials etc, using [conditional filtering](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx/)

Comment: As you mentioned, I tried to use HttpModule.
I created function for BeginRequest.
But to my surprise when I did request from the client. The BeginRequest execute multiple times.
I don't understand how can it be.
Multiple request when I did one request from the client?

Comment: Did the page have images/css/jss? If so, they're probably firing the HTTP Module as well, as it will run for ANYTHING that runs through the pipeline. You'll probably need to add some code to your module so that it only executes on pages requests only.